# Does the continuous image of a disc contain an embedded disc?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, embeddings

Let $\phi:\Bbb D^2\to\Bbb R^n$ be a continuous mapping of the 2-disc $\Bbb D^2$ that is injective on the boundary $\partial\Bbb D^2=\Bbb S^1$. Does its image contain an embedded disc with the same boundary? That is, is there an injective map $\psi:\Bbb D^2\to\Bbb R^n$ with $\phi(x)=\psi(x)$ for $x\in\partial \Bbb D^2$ and $\mathrm{im}(\psi)\subseteq\mathrm{im}(\phi)$? Does this depend on $n$? Is it at least true if $\phi$ is a PL map?

This is meant to be an analogy to how every curve between two points contains a non-self-crossing curve between the same points (at least I believe that this is true).

$\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is the Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: @Oleg For $n=2$ you mean? This seems plausible. I would be most interested in $n=3,4$.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Hm, I do not immediately see the relation of my question to the Schoenflies problem for $n\ge 3$. Can you elaborate? I still think that the horned sphere (even a less wild version) might be a counterexample in 3D.

Comment: I missed that your map goes to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The answer is no for $n=3$ - attach a disk (necessary with self-intersections) to a non-trivial knot. I don't know the answer for $n>3$.

Comment: @Oleg Yes, that should suffice as a counterexample. Thank you. It also yields a counterexample for $n\ge 4$ because we can just make $\phi$ map your counterexample to a 3-dimensional subspace, and since $\psi$ must be contained in $\phi$ we are back at the 3-dimensional problem.

Comment: I don't follow you. The fact that a projection on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not injective says nothing about the map to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin I don't need any projections. Just use that $\mathrm{im}(\psi)\subseteq\mathrm{im}(\phi)$. So whatever dimension $\phi$ "lives in" is forced on $\psi$. And you can choose $\phi$ essentially 3-dimensional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is "yes" for $n=2$ (that is the Schoenflies theorem).
For $n>2$ the answer is "no". Consider a non-trivial knot $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and a continuous injective map $\partial\mathbb{D}^2\mapsto K$. Extend that map to a map $\mathbb{D}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$. The resulting disk has a knot as a boundary, so it must have a self-intersection. As pointed out by M. Winter, that gives a counter-example for all $n\geq3$.

Another way to construct counter-examples is to consider an embedded disk with a single point of a self-intersection. For $n\ge 4$ one may consider a disk with a transversal self-intersection. For $n=3$ one may consider a disk that touches itself -- fold a piece of paper and pinch two halves together at one point.