# Can a closed null-homotopic curve be filled in by a disc?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, embeddings

Let $U\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be an open set and $\gamma\subset U$ a closed [null-homotopic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/null+homotopy) curve in $U$ (i.e. it can be contracted to a point). Then is there an embedded disc $D\subset U$ with boundary $\gamma$?

This is a follow up on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/458234/108884), from which I know the answer for

- $n=2$: Yes, using the Schoenflies theorem.
- $n=3$: No if $\gamma$ is a non-trivial knot. Is it true if $\gamma$ is the unknot?

I am mostly interested in $n=4$ and everything being piecewise linear, but a more general answer is welcome as well.

Comment: The answer is no for $n=4$. Take a disk with a transversal self-intersection. Then a sufficiently small neighborhood of it will be a counter-example.

Comment: @Oleg Hm, I don't immediately see why this is a counterexample. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $D_1$ is a transversely self-intersecting disk and $U$ is a small enough neighborhood of $D_1$, then any disk in $U$ attached to the $\gamma=\partial D_1$ must also have a self-intersection.

Comment: @Oleg I am not sure this is true. Couldn't I push the self-intersection to and then beyond the disc's boundary, modifying the disc only in an arbitrarily small neighbourhood? Having said that, shouldn't something like this work starting from every null-homotopy (make all intersections transversal and push them to the boundary)? I think your comment is right if $\gamma$ lies in the boundary of $U$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My construction does not work. And it seems that your idea works for any smooth $\gamma$.